# Convert word doc to pdf. Not able to replace existing pdf documnet for converting word to pdf

Tags: powershell, ms-word, pdf-generation

I am trying to convert *Word document* to *PDF* using following script.

What I am doing is:

- creating an empty PDF file first as output file
- and then replacing that file with the converted word file.

My script is as follows:

```
#Convert Word formats to PDF 
Param(
 [string]$inputPath,
 [string]$outputPath
)
$wdFormatPDF = 17
$File = $inputPath
$Word=NEW-OBJECT –COMOBJECT WORD.APPLICATION
$Doc=$Word.Documents.Open($File)
$Doc.saveas([ref]$outputPath,[ref]$wdFormatPDF)
$Doc.close()
$Word.Quit() 
$Word = $null 
[gc]::collect() 
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

The `Doc.saveas()` function is not replacing the output pdf file.
Where as if I don't create the output file before and just specify a dummy file name to output, its creating that file.

But how can I replace the PDF file I am creating. The PDF file is created through JAVA. Running script through powershell through java command run.

The cmd is as follows,

```
 powershell -NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass   
   -File "D:/wordToPdf.ps1" -inputPath D:/Files/TestLetter.docx 
   -outputPath D:/Files/PDF_TestLetter.pdf
```

The `TestLetter` is word document which to be converted and `PDF_TestLetter` is already created empty PDF document. Hence need to replace this PDF document.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation for [SaveAs()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.saveas.aspx) function there is no way to replace the already existing document.
I'd suggest to try deleting file if exists ([see link](http://stevehardie.com/2012/09/powershell-delete-file-if-exists/)) before actually saving file.

Comment: Ok then I guess I will just provide the file path with file name I want and new PDF file will get created with it. Even this solution is fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create your blank PDF file (I'm not sure why you want to do this). Call it `filename.pdf`.
2. Rename `filename.pdf` to `filename.pdf.bak`
3. Generate your output PDF file. If this generation fails, delete the file and rename `filename.pdf.bak` back to to `filename.pdf`
4. Delete `filename.pdf.bak.`